# password with minimum 6 character doesn't work [rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading the book of Agile web development with rails 4

in the user model I have a password validation that cannot be less than 6 character

```
validates :password_digest, length: {minimum: 6}
```

But actually when I create a new user, it allow me to do it with less than 6. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: are you validating password_digest instead of password?

Comment: Is it possible that you hash the password before the validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be short - you're validating the wrong field. Replace :password_digest with :password.

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

A bit longer explanation here:
I've opened a book and looking at Chapter 14 (named 'Task I: Logging In').
Looks like you have users table with columns 'name', 'password_digest' and 'salt'.
Samples from the book describe how to hash password, mix it with salt and store result in a database. The point is - your 'password_digest' will be long enough even if you generate this from one letter. You can try it by yourself in irb:

```
require 'digest'
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('a') #=> "ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a2..."
```

So, you shouldn't validate length of hashed password. Instead you should validate 'password' attribute itself.

Comment: it is true thanks for this detailled answer, I was confused because in the table I have password_digest.

Comment: Not a big deal. I was learning Rails by this book too. We can exchange  contacts if you like.

Comment: it is a great book by the way, yes sure it is allowed to send pm here? there is also a group on skype, they work on RoR with cucumber and rspec if you'd like I can give you the contact

Answer (score 2):

**Encrypted**

You're validating `password_digest` - this indicates it's the encrypted password?

As mentioned in the comments, unless your form input will be called `password_digest`, it's likely going to be hashed *before* the validation is performed, making this value always be over 6 chars

The immediate fix for this (although I'm not sure if it's completely correct) is to validate the "naked" password. This will validate the password as in-putted, not the hashed version:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
end
```